# Strict Nat on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

This is an older topic and shouldn't be questioned but I cannot fix the nat type on my xbox. I have done everything possible. I ain't a techy person... At all... mostly no clue what I am doing. But I did everything I could find on how to fix this problem. I have it wired to my Gateway Router which is a Arris DG1670. But in all seriousness. I have tried a lot. Wireless, Port Forwarding, Static IPs, DMZ, nothing works at all. Maybe it is the router, me, ethernet cable, idk. It is striaght up plugged into it. My router doesnt notice the xbox one when it is plugged in but notices it when wireless but it still stayed strict with portforwarding. Idk... I am a fool with this stuff.... pls help

Comment: a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=xbox%20one%20strict%20nat%20Arris%20DG1670) brought up many other common issues, so it could possible the router is just incompatible. Have you tried wiring the console directly to your internet modem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "My router doesnt notice the xbox one when it is plugged in[...]". Also, do you have any other devices using the same router? For example, the Xbox 360 uses mostly the exact same ports and routers, at least the affordable ones, are only able to forward one port to one device. If you have multiple devices that need to have the same port forwarded, the router will assign priorities which could mean your One, although you added the settings, might not have the ports forwarded, resulting in a strict NAT.

Answer (score -1):

I have been successful with putting  my Xbox on DMZ with this router. At first I had trouble with the DMZ until I read somewhere that you have to make sure that you enable your firewall. So you go to the firewall tab and enable firewall with The DMZ settings and it should work. Remember though you can't have any other settings such as port forwarding or it may not work so clear out any other settings you may have tried.